# How can I access the value of ngModel within a separate component?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a component that has data binded using ngModel. I'm trying to access that specific data within the separate component, but I've not been able to figure out how. I've not found anything useful online on how I can accomplish this either. Is this even possible?

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ProductBigFactory, ProductForProfileComponent } from "@terra/product";

@Component({
    selector: "profile",
    templateUrl: " <div class="large-12 columns">
            <label for="description-areaoftext" id="description">{{PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION_SUDO_NAME}}</label>
            <input-wysiwyg name="description" [limit]="2500" [showContentProgressBar]="true" [(ngModel)]="product.description" required></input-wysiwyg>
        </div>"
})
export class SpecificProfileComponent extends ProductForProfileComponent {
  
    constructor(productForFactory: ProductForFactory) {
        super(productForFactory);
    }


    public ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log("The description is: " +this.product.description);
    }

}
```

Comment: Nothing is right in your code. Your HTML is invalid, you use variables that do not exist ... And you provide no context or no specific code to help you out !

Comment: @temp_user I hope this is a bit better.